# Problems about dual boot (Windows 7 Ice and Ubuntu)

Tags: 12.04

I tried to do Dual Boot with Windows 7 Ice, but the partition who contains Ubuntu doesn't show in any mode.

Can someone give me instructions for a correct Dual Boot?
Thanks.

Comment: Adding information about your existing partitions would help

Answer (score 0):

[There](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot) you go.

Typing `ubuntu dual boot` to Google is not so hard, is it? ;)

Comment: I tried it, but I found wrong or incorrect answers.